# how to make lower decimal javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to lower decimal, can anyone help me to show how to use "toFixed" in this code? or if there is any other way?

miniseconds/1000/60/60/24 so I get the number of days.

```
function () {
  try {
    if ({{cookie - firstSeen}}) {
        var now = new Date().getTime()
        var time2conversion = now - {{cookie - firstSeen}}
        return time2conversion/1000/60/60/24
    }else{
        return undefined
  }
 }catch(e) {
  return undefined;
  }
}
```

The result is 1.3964438888888886, but it would be for ex. 1.39.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to round a number to two decimals?

Comment: Happens a lot - try `0.1 + 0.2`. Hint: It doesn't come to `0.3`.

Comment: you can use `.toFixed(2)` if you want to have 2 values after the comma

Comment: What syntax is this?

Comment: Yes, correct @StefanN

Comment: `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` [Visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/2932057)

Comment: @zer00ne do you mean that I will add this code after the line  `return time2conversion/1000/60/60/24`

Comment: @cloned something like `print(time2conversion.toPrint(2));` ?

Comment: Where did you get `toPrint` from? And if you need the function to `return` the value with 2 decimal points then do so: `time2conversion/1000/60/60/24.toFixed(2)`

Comment: @cloned Ah sorry, i was reading some example. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

u can follow this format
var number.toFixed(2);

Comment: something like this `print(time2conversion.toPrint(2));` ?

Comment: based on your example probably will be time2conversion.toFixed(2);